# .htaccess: How to permanently redirect a dynamic address, with no-follow, do-not-index directive using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following problem. The link format below no longer exist:

`photos.domain.com/web/poppic.php?n=[any number from 0 to the roof]`

Ej,: `photos.domain.com/web/poppic.php?n=30`

I replaced it, a year ago, to just: `photos.domain.com/`

Years after, I am still having tons of 404 errors.
I need a permanent redirect, and an htaccess difective for search engines to do not follow and to no longer index that old link.

I tried `rewriterule ^web\/poppic\.php?n=30 "http\:\/\/photos\.domain\.com" [R=301,L]` will work. HOWEVER, I requires to write each line, from 0 to 9999999999999999999999999:
`rewriterule ^web\/poppic\.php?n=0 "http\:\/\/photos\.domain\.com" [R=301,L]`
`rewriterule ^web\/poppic\.php?n=1 "http\:\/\/photos\.domain\.com" [R=301,L]`
`rewriterule ^web\/poppic\.php?n=2 "http\:\/\/photos\.domain\.com" [R=301,L]`
etc.

How can I do it with a variable, to replace `php?n=[number]` for `php?n=$variable` (Or something like that)?

Also, it is not telling crawlers to do not follow/index the page.

Could you please help?

Comment: @faa ???...as in...`rewriterule ^web\/poppic\.php?n=([\d]*) "http\:\/\/photos\.domain\.com" [R=301,L]` ? Can you please add your complete answer/code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't match against the query string inside of a rewrite rule using apache's mod_rewrite. You need to use a rewrite condition and match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^n=[0-9]+
RewriteRule ^web/poppic\.php$ /? [L,R=301]
```

Not sure how your original rule:

```
rewriterule ^web\/poppic\.php?n=30 "http\:\/\/photos\.domain\.com" [R=301,L]
```

ever worked. It doesn't work for me under apache 2.2 or 2.4.